# Проблема с "jquery .load()"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть папка в которой подключен jquery, потом файл `learn.html` и файл `menu.html` - в котором храниться мое меню для всех страниц. В папке есть еще пару файлов. В файле `learn.html` Я прописала следующий скрипт -  `<script>$(function() { $('#menu').load('menu.html') });</script>` и создала див `id="menu"`. В Файле `menu.html` есть меню -

`<a href="index1.html">hello</a>

 <a href="index2.html">hi</a>
 <a href="index3.html">bye</a>`

Если я не ошибаюсь на странице `learn.html` в диве `#menu` должно было бы  появиться меню которое находиться в файле `menu.html`?
Так же при открытии панели разработчика в хроме, выводит следующее сообщение - `jquery.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/*/*/*/menu.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` Я не доконца понимаю что это значит. Как это исправить? Буду благодарна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На официальном сайте https://api.jquery.com/load/ первая строка

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML
>   into the matched elements.

.load() загружает данные с сервера. Создайте сервер и будет все работать